# Limiting simultaneously running asyncio coroutines with semaphores in a background thread

Tags: multithreading, semaphore, coroutine, event-loop, python-asyncio

As an experiment with Python's new asyncio module, I created the following snippet to process a set of long running actions (jobs) in a background worker.

In an attempt to control the number of simultaneously running jobs, I introduced a semaphore in a *with block* (line 56). However, with the semaphore in place, it seems that the acquired locks are never released because after completion (the callbacks are executed) the waiting jobs don't start. When I ditch the *with block*, everything works as expected.

```
import asyncio

from queue import Queue, Empty
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Thread


class BackgroundWorker(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._keep_running = True
        self._waiting_coros = Queue()
        self._tasks = []
        self._loop = None    # Loop must be initialized in child thread.
        self.limit_simultaneous_processes = asyncio.Semaphore(2)

    def stop(self):
        self._keep_running = False

    def run(self):
        self._loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()       # Implicit creation of the loop only happens in the main thread.
        asyncio.set_event_loop(self._loop)          # Since this is a child thread, we need to do in manually.
        self._loop.run_until_complete(self.process_coros())

    def submit_coro(self, coro, callback=None):
        self._waiting_coros.put((coro, callback))

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def process_coros(self):
        while self._keep_running:
            try:
                while True:
                    coro, callback = self._waiting_coros.get_nowait()
                    task = asyncio.async(coro())
                    if callback:
                        task.add_done_callback(callback)
                    self._tasks.append(task)
            except Empty as e:
                pass
            yield from asyncio.sleep(3)     # sleep so the other tasks can run


background_worker = BackgroundWorker()


class Job(object):
    def __init__(self, idx):
        super().__init__()
        self._idx = idx

    def process(self):
        background_worker.submit_coro(self._process, self._process_callback)

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def _process(self):
        with (yield from background_worker.limit_simultaneous_processes):
            print("received processing slot %d" % self._idx)
            start = datetime.now()
            yield from asyncio.sleep(2)
            print("processing %d took %s" % (self._idx, str(datetime.now() - start)))

    def _process_callback(self, future):
        print("callback %d triggered" % self._idx)


def main():
    print("starting worker...")
    background_worker.start()

    for idx in range(10):
        download_job = Job(idx)
        download_job.process()

    command = None
    while command != "quit":
        command = input("enter 'quit' to stop the program: \n")

    print("stopping...")
    background_worker.stop()
    background_worker.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Can anyone help me shed some light on this behavior? Why are isn't the semaphore incremented when the *with block* is cleared?

Comment: I don't see your concern: semaphore count is decreased and increased in your code example as expected.

Comment: Did you run the code? If I do so, the callbacks for the first two jobs are executed but the other coroutines in the loop don't start executing. I assume they are still waiting to acquire a lock from the semaphore, but I might be wrong here. Maybe they are waiting for something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered the bug: the semaphore is initialized with an implicit eventloop from the main thread, not the one explicitly set when the thread is started with `run()`.

Fixed version:

```
import asyncio

from queue import Queue, Empty
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Thread


class BackgroundWorker(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._keep_running = True
        self._waiting_coros = Queue()
        self._tasks = []
        self._loop = None                           # Loop must be initialized in child thread.
        self.limit_simultaneous_processes = None    # Semaphore must be initialized after the loop is set.

    def stop(self):
        self._keep_running = False

    def run(self):
        self._loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()       # Implicit creation of the loop only happens in the main thread.
        asyncio.set_event_loop(self._loop)          # Since this is a child thread, we need to do in manually.
        self.limit_simultaneous_processes = asyncio.Semaphore(2)
        self._loop.run_until_complete(self.process_coros())

    def submit_coro(self, coro, callback=None):
        self._waiting_coros.put((coro, callback))

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def process_coros(self):
        while self._keep_running:
            try:
                while True:
                    coro, callback = self._waiting_coros.get_nowait()
                    task = asyncio.async(coro())
                    if callback:
                        task.add_done_callback(callback)
                    self._tasks.append(task)
            except Empty as e:
                pass
            yield from asyncio.sleep(3)     # sleep so the other tasks can run


background_worker = BackgroundWorker()


class Job(object):
    def __init__(self, idx):
        super().__init__()
        self._idx = idx

    def process(self):
        background_worker.submit_coro(self._process, self._process_callback)

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def _process(self):
        with (yield from background_worker.limit_simultaneous_processes):
            print("received processing slot %d" % self._idx)
            start = datetime.now()
            yield from asyncio.sleep(2)
            print("processing %d took %s" % (self._idx, str(datetime.now() - start)))

    def _process_callback(self, future):
        print("callback %d triggered" % self._idx)


def main():
    print("starting worker...")
    background_worker.start()

    for idx in range(10):
        download_job = Job(idx)
        download_job.process()

    command = None
    while command != "quit":
        command = input("enter 'quit' to stop the program: \n")

    print("stopping...")
    background_worker.stop()
    background_worker.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```